# How to read content of sftp text file line by line and save into database?

Tags: php, laravel, file

I get the file content using through the server

```
Storage::disk('sftp')->get($k);
```

ps: $k  is the path of the txt file in server.

This will return

```
No.|Desc|Qty|
1|abc|1|
2|efg|2|
3|hhh|3|
```

How can i read this content line by line and save to database or i need to do locally?

Comment: What's `$k` set to?

Comment: @FrankerZ Sorry, forgot to mention that $k is the path of txt file, by using this statement it will return me content of the txt file.

Comment: So I assume that the return value is a string?

Comment: Have a look into: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: No idea how to read in server.

Comment: Is the return value a `string` or some other type?

Comment: @CodiMech25 it returned as string, i knew how to do it locally, but is that a way i can directly read the line of the file stored in server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing the content line by line can be achieved via this solution:

```
$data = Storage::disk('sftp')->get($k);
$lines = explode("\n", $data);

foreach ($lines as $line_number => $line)
{
    // do something with the line
}
```

`$line_number` will be counted from 0.

Comment: Yeah, i also figured out this way. Just curious is it practical to read file in server and store data to database then delete the file from server?

Comment: It depends on your needs. What do you want to do with the data etc.

Comment: It's POS data, just pull the data and store in my system.

Comment: Then there's nothing wrong if the data can't be accessed in a better way.